# Is it possible to change TimePicker default texts?

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I need to change default text values on `timepicker` in android (java) and can't figure out how to do that.

I've found `.setTitle` and `.setmessage`, but when clicking on keyborad icon in Timepicker dialog:

[image]

and shows another way to change time it has another title and default message as instructions that I would like to change Second timepicker dialog output

[image].

I'm calling a simple `TimePickerDialog`. Any suggestions? regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this out. This works for me good.

```
 @Subscribe
 public void setAlarm(OnAlarmClickEvent event) {
    arrivalTime = event.arrivalTime;
    alarmTime = event.arrivalTime;
    int reminder = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_key_alarm_reminder), "5"));
    alarmTime = alarmTime.minusMinutes(reminder);

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
            this,
            this,
            alarmTime.getHourOfDay(),
            alarmTime.getMinuteOfHour(),
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)
    );
    timePickerDialog.setTitle(R.string.alarm_dialog_title);
    timePickerDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alarm_dialog_message_fmt, DateUtils.formatTime(arrivalTime)));
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```